# How can I disable an item in RadmulticolumnCombobox WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I have a Telerik RadMulticolumnCombobox that populates from an Itemsourceprovider, what I would like is to set `isEnable` to false for a specific item in this control.

The problem is that I cannot find any property that releases this task.

```
<telerik:RadMultiColumnComboBox DisplayMemberPath="LastName"
                                NullText="Select employee to handle the order..."
                                Width="300"
                                DropDownWidth="530"
                                DropDownHeight="255">
 

  <telerik:RadMultiColumnComboBox.ItemsSourceProvider>
        <telerik:GridViewItemsSourceProvider AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" >
            <telerik:GridViewItemsSourceProvider.Columns>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="First Name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Last Name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding City}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Hire Date" DataMemberBinding="{Binding HireDate}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Orders Count" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Orders.Count}" />
            </telerik:GridViewItemsSourceProvider.Columns>
        </telerik:GridViewItemsSourceProvider>
    </telerik:RadMultiColumnComboBox.ItemsSourceProvider>
</telerik:RadMultiColumnComboBox>
```

[image]

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem !!
I can't believe the solution is that easy.

I have created a `rowStyle` and I have created a `propertyChanged` in my class

```
     <telerik:GridViewItemsSourceProvider.RowStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewRow">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsSelected}">
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </telerik:GridViewItemsSourceProvider.RowStyle>
```

and this my class :

```
    public class MyModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
     {
    

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
      {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (isSelected != value)
            {
                isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) 
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

and I have set the value of this property in my main like this :

```
var models = new List<MyModel>();
// ....

foreach ( var m in models)
    m.IsSelected = true;
var item = mycombob.selectedItem as MyModel;
item.IsSelected = false; // disable the selected item for example
```